# An rough implementation of `std::is_constructible`

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++20

As a challenge/fun activity/task, I have implemented my version of `std::is_constructible`.

Here is the source code:

```cpp
#include <cbrainx/cbrainx.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename ...V>
auto aux(long) -> cbx::false_type;

template <typename T, typename ...V>
static auto aux(int) -> cbx::type_switch_t<
    cbx::branch<cbx::false_type,
                cbx::detail::void_t<decltype(::new(cbx::declval<void *>()) T{cbx::declval<V>()...})>>,
    cbx::otherwise<cbx::true_type>>;

template <typename T, typename ...V>
auto is_constructible() -> decltype(aux<T, V...>(0));

struct X {
  X() {
    std::cout << "constructed..." << std::endl;
  }

 private:
  X(int) {
  }

 public:
  X(const X &) = delete;

  X(X &&) {}

  ~X() {
    std::cout << "destroyed..." << std::endl;
  }

  static void xd() {
    X{1};
    std::cout << decltype(is_constructible<X, int>())::value << std::endl;
  }
};

auto main() -> int {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;

  std::cout << decltype(is_constructible<X, X>())::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << decltype(is_constructible<X, X &>())::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << decltype(is_constructible<X, X &&>())::value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**IMPORTANT:**

- `cbx::false_type` is equivalent to `std::false_type`. It has a `value` of type `bool`. Likewise `cbx::true_type`.
- `cbx::type_switch_t` is equivalent to `switch` clause but, for types and evaluated statically at compile time.
- `cbx::branch` is like the `if` branch. The first argument is the condition and must have a `value` of type `bool`. The second argument is the type itself.
- `cbx::otherwise` is like the `else` branch.

### Things I know

1. It does not work for private constructors. (I am okay with that!)
2. It's a rough implementation.

### Things I want to know

1. Is this implementation correct?
2. Am I missing anything?
3. How close it is to the actual `std::is_constructible`?
4. How can I improve?

**C++ Standard: 20**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to cleanly separate your `is_constructible` from the "test harness" code that follows it — either with a `//-----` comment, or by putting your thing in a namespace, or something.

Your thing is a *function* template, whereas the standard `std::is_constructible` is a type-trait (that is, a *class* template).

Without seeing the definitions of `branch`, `otherwise`, etc., it's hard to judge whether your code is even correct, let alone performant.

You name both your template parameter `T` and your parameter *pack* `V...` with singular names. It would be helpful to name the pack with a plural name, e.g. `Vs...` or `Args...`.

Your unit tests take the form of `std::cout << foo`. Prefer to use `static_assert(foo)`, so that the compiler will tell you whether your tests passed or failed — you shouldn't have to eyeball the terminal output to tell whether you implemented `is_constructible` right!

---

You should become familiar with the traditional SFINAE idioms. For a simple type-trait like `is_constructible`, where all you want to know is whether a particular expression is well-formed, the idiom is

```
template<class T, class = void>
struct is_fooable : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_fooable<T, decltype((
    your-expression-here
), void())> : std::true_type {};
```

Or, since you tagged this question `c++20`, you could just use a `requires`-expression:

```
template<class T>
struct is_fooable : std::bool_constant<requires {
    your-expression-here;
}> {};
```

In the specific case of `is_constructible`, the expression you care about is `new T(args...)`. So you might write

```
template<class, class T, class... Args>
struct is_constructible_impl : std::false_type {};

template<class T, class... Args>
struct is_constructible_impl<decltype((
    new T(std::declval<Args>()...)
), void()), T, Args...> : std::true_type {};

template<class T, class... Args>
struct is_constructible : is_constructible_impl<void, T, Args...> {};
```

Or:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
struct is_constructible : std::bool_constant<requires (Args&&... args) {
    new T(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
}> {};
```

([Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/PEfvxGch9))

---

By writing unit tests and comparing them to the standard `std::is_constructible`, we soon find a problem: `std::is_constructible<int&, int&>::value` is `true`, but our `new T(args...)` formulation yields `false`, because you can't `new` a reference type. Solving this problem is left as an exercise for the reader, because I'm too lazy to look it up right now. :)

Comment: Did I do it write? https://godbolt.org/z/T1Kxrjbch @Quuxplusone

Comment: Are there any other edge/special/unhandled cases? @Quuxplusone

Comment: @MansoorAhmedMemon: Only one way to find out! Write test cases and compare your answers against `std::is_constructible`'s answers. [Try tricky things.](https://twitter.com/brenankeller/status/1068615953989087232) https://godbolt.org/z/T1Kxrjbch seems to mess up on `is_constructible<int&, float&>`. The expression you chose to SFINAE on, `T(x)`, can do a [hidden reinterpret_cast](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/01/22/expression-list-in-functional-cast/).